# How to express this action in English succinctly: "You put on just one leg of your shorts"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

Look at this image

[image]

Imagine it's a girl.

**How to express this action in English succinctly ?**

*My toddler often puts on just one leg of her shorts if the legs are very wide.*

or

*My toddler often puts her 2 legs in just one leg of her shorts if the legs are very wide.*

Comment: A fairly unique situation. There is no standard way to say this. I personally wouldn’t use “...put on...” as the verb since it suggests success in clothing yourself and this is a failure. I’d prefer something like, “You put both your legs through one leg of your shorts.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is understandable. Remember the word "both" means "all of two" and should be used whenever it applies.

> My toddler often puts both legs in just one leg of her shorts if the legs are very wide.

I think the way I'd personally phrase it, assuming this only happens briefly by accident in the process of putting on her shorts, is "Sometimes my toddler gets caught in one leg of her shorts if they're too wide."